What model is appropriate for measuring the correlation between two proportions?
Explanation: I have a dataset (say n=100 samples) with two data types associated with each sample (genetic and ecological). I'm resampling the dataset such that I take a random draw of n samples (2, 3, 4...up to n) and calculate the genetic and ecological "representativeness" of that subsample as compared to the entire dataset; thus, each metric is a proportion. For each n, I calculate these "representativeness" metrics multiple times using different random subsamples, to account for the stochasticity of random sampling. As n increases, both metrics necessarily approach 100% (in a logarithmic manner).
Goal: I want to measure the correlation between the two metrics, to see if one (ecological) can be used to reliably predict the other (genetic). I'm doing this by building a linear model in R where ecological representativeness (across all sample sizes and replicates per sample size) is the explanatory variable and genetic representativeness is the response, and calculating the R-squared value of that model.
Question: Because both explanatory and response variables are bounded within a range [0:100], do I need to use anything more complex than a linear model to accommodate this data? Do I need to transform the data in any way prior to passing it into a model?

(Context: I realize this is a rudimentary question; I've taken some graduate coursework in linear modeling, but it was many years ago. I've explored some alternative methods for modeling this data (e.g. here), but I would like to understand if/why something more complex than a standard linear model is warranted.)
Thanks very much for any assistance!

Hi, welcome on Cross Validated. Indeed, you will need a more appropriate model to study the association between two proportions. I recommend the use of beta regression which is specifically well suited for this problem.

What do you mean by "correlation"? That you do not want to use the usual Pearson correlation leaves me wondering why. Pearson correlation might not be the right tool for your work, but that has little to do with the lack of normality (which is an assumption for certain hypothesis tests and confidence interval calculations, but Pearson correlation does not require normality to make sense).

@MangnierLoïc thanks for the tip. Do you have any suggestions for running such a beta regression in R? Or, if you could direct me to useful sources for understanding beta regression generally, I'd appreciate it.

@Dave I'm not inherently opposed to a Pearson correlation, and will look into that solution.

@akoontz11 the betareg package in r implemented all you need for beta regression. From my side, I would always prefer to have some kind of regression models instead of an univariate test or metric, we often have complete tools for inspection.

As suggested by @MangnierLoïc, a beta regression (for instance, using the betareg package in R) seems suitable for building a model using variables described above.
I'll also note this question led me to consider what type of relationship I'm trying to capture and whether a formal correlation or something simpler was appropriate. For measuring just the goodness of fit between the representativeness proportions above, a metric like the root mean square error should also suffice.
